# Multiple Gatsby wrapRootElement (implementing Auth0 and Redux)

Tags: react-redux, gatsby, auth0

Im trying to implement Gatsby with both Auth0 and Redux

As both Auth0 and Redux needs to use wrapRootElement in gatsby-browser.js, how can I merge the two in order to use them successfully in gatsby? Thanks in advance

**gatsby-browser.js**

```
// used by Auth0
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <SessionCheck>{element}</SessionCheck>
}

// used by Redux
export { default as wrapRootElement } from "./src/state/ReduxWrapper"
```

**gatsby-ssr.js**

Take note Im also importing then exporting ReduxWrapper in gatsby-ssr.js

```
// export { default as wrapRootElement } from "./src/store/ReduxWrapper"
```

**ReduxWrapper.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { createStore as reduxCreateStore } from "redux"
import rootReducer from "."

const createStore = () => reduxCreateStore(rootReducer)

export default ({ element }) => (
  <Provider store={createStore()}>{element}</Provider>
)
```

I tried doing the following in **gatsby-browser.js** but it returns a blank page

```
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <SessionCheck>
      <ReduxWrapper>{element}</ReduxWrapper>
    </SessionCheck>
  )
}
```

Comment: What happens if you do the same thing in `gatsby-ssr.js` as you have tried in `gatsby-browser.js`?

Comment: i just tried. can't. it render a blank screen

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Jeremy Albright, here's the solution to above issue. Happy coding

Basically, element should be passed as a prop to ReduxWrapper and NOT as a children

**gatsby-browser.js**

```
export const wrapRootElement = props => {
  return (
    <SessionCheck>
      <ReduxWrapper {...props} />
    </SessionCheck>
  )
}
```

Comment: This worked. Is there a link to the doc that you used or was it found through trial and error?

Comment: I haven't touched this topic for a while so can't recall where I learnt this